# React Native project fails to load when I run from Xcode

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, metro-bundler

When I run the react native project in xcode I get the following error. Metro bunlder is failing for some reason.

This is the error shows up in the terminal window that launches.

```
error ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir '/var/folders/h6/952khgzj1zncqsd5rdsdk5240000gn/T/metro-cache/00'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir '/var/folders/h6/952khgzj1zncqsd5rdsdk5240000gn/T/metro-cache/00'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:757:3)
    at Function.sync (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at FileStore._createDirs (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/FileStore.js:94:14)
    at new FileStore (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/FileStore.js:27:10)
    at getDefaultValues (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:164:5)
    at /Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:191:12
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:14:24)
    at _next (/Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:34:9)
    at /Users/aaaa/Documents/newton/connectedblue/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:39:7`
```

The project used to work without any issues but not fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after creating a directories as given in the error message, it started to work.